# How to bulk upload in App Engine with reference field?

Tags: google-app-engine, model

I want to bulk upload data for following entity:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name  = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    type  = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    refer = db.SelfReferenceProperty()
```

What is best way to load this data into appspot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The method you want to use is deprecated. Try to use YAML configuration file for bulk uploading.

You can see the tutorial here: [Google App Engine, Uploading and Downloading Data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuring_the_Bulk_Loader)

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you are creating object for each entity and the put it in some king of queue that proceed them one by one(or by groups of X). Can`t you just create key object from the reference key(if you have it like string)?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your data already has some sort of natural key - or it couldn't include a self reference property. Use [generate_key](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Advanced-Bulk-Loading-part-2-Customization) to specify a key name for each loaded entity, and a lambda function for the 'refer' field to generate a key that references the appropriate entity.

Comment: Part of the problem is data doesn't have natural key. It is hierarchical in nature. Only unique way to identify a model instance is through path in the hierarchy. BTW, thanks for the link. I got know new stuff about bulk loader.